# Retrieve class of return value in extension function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I want to replace this function:

```
fun <T : Parcelable> Parcel.readObject(result: Parcelable.Creator<T>): T {
    return this.readParcelable(result::class.java.classLoader) as T
}
```

with a function like:

```
fun <T : Parcelable> Parcel.readObject(): T {
    return this.readParcelable(T::class.java.classLoader) as T
}
```

So I want it to retrieve the class of the return value and get the classLoader of that class. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could accomplish that by using the `reified` keyword as follows:

```
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Parcel.readObject(): T {
    return this.readParcelable(T::class.java.classLoader) as T
}
```

You can read more about `reified` parameters in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters)

Comment: that might be even simplifiable to: `inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Parcel.readObject() : T = readParcelable(T::class.java.classLoader)`...